# OpenERP 6.1: Invoice the "shipped amount" hours of a finished task?

Tags: odoo

As written in the [docs (here)](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/book/4/4_13_Projects/4_13_Projects_management.html/) I can autmatically create Tasks from Sales Orders. This is working fine. Now I want to invoice the total time that was spend for this task. So I set "Invoice on: Shipped Quantities" and "Invoice Policy: Invoice based on delivery" for the Sales Order but the created Invoice contains the orderd amount of hours anyway.

How to configure OpenERP, the SalesOrder or the Task to generate the Invoice with the correct amount of hours after finishing the Task correctly ?